# Why does the Syncfusion GridControl cause a StackOverflowException in the ComponentResourceManager's GetX methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, syncfusion

I know that this is a very specific question and that the behavior I am going to describe is hard to reproduce, but maybe someone has stumbled upon a similar issue.

I have two Visual Studio projects, *Base* and *Derived*. Within *Base* I created the `UserControl` inheritor `BaseUserControl` and add a Syncfusion (Version 9.403.0.62) `GridControl` and an `ImageList` containing some images to it. Then in *Derived* I derive a `DerivedUserControl` from `BaseUserControl`. When I now try to open the visual designer, Visual Studio 2010 crashes. If I attach the debugger from a second Visual Studio instance to the one I use to open the designer, I see a `StackOverflowException` occuring in the `InitializeComponent` method of `BaseUserControl`. It is thrown when the `ComponentResourceManager`'s `GetObject` method is called to load the first image of the `ImageList`.

Without the Syncfusion `GridControl` everything works fine and I can't observe this issue with Visual Studio 2008 either. It is reproduceable on every machine within our company. We use Windows XP SP3 and .NET 3.5.

I cannot make out a direct connection from the `GridControl` to `ComponentResourceManager` and hence the `StackOverflowExcpetion`. Maybe someone can make me see what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample is created with two Base/Derived projects which includes a GridControl and an ImageList. Some `*.png` images are attached into the ImageList. The reference has been given as mentioned in your query. I am afraid that I am unable to replicate the Vs2010 crash through this way. The designer of the Derivedproject has been displayed without `StackOverflow` exception. Here is the tested sample for your reference:

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/Support/DirectTrac/1/ImageCell_CS-1414783889.zip

And, ensure the following things along with this,

1. Check whether the assembly ‘Syncfusion.Core’ is referenced.
2. Check with your licensing details too.
3. Change the ‘SpecficVersion’ of Syncfusion referred assemblies’ property to ‘False’